# Binding a Command not Working for ListView with Itemsource

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, binding, mvvmcross

I'm trying to add a Clickable ListView-Cell, but I'm probably getting conflicts with the binding.

Each cell should be like a button navigating to a new Page including a given Object.
I already tried with "TapGestureRecognizer".

```xml
<ListView x:Name="ListView" HasUnevenRows="True" SelectionMode="Single" >


                    <ListView.ItemsSource>
                    <x:Array Type="{x:Type clients:MinRepresentation}">
                        <clients:MinRepresentation Id="123456789" PlannedStartTime="01-01-2019" PlannedEndTime="01-12-2019"  />
                        <clients:MinRepresentation Id="555555555" PlannedStartTime="12-12-2019" PlannedEndTime="12-12-2019"  />
                    </x:Array>
                </ListView.ItemsSource>

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Grid Padding="5">
                                    <Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                        <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OrderDetailsCommand}"/>
                                    </Grid.GestureRecognizers>
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"  />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                         [Cell-Template]
                                    </Grid>
                            </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: OrderDetailsCommand is on the item ViewModel in the collection you are presenting as the ItemsSource?

Comment: Yes it is. And its working accessing it from menuitem

Comment: So `MinRepresentation` has the command?

Comment: "MinRepresentation" is an Object, and OrderDetailsCommand opens a new View...

Comment: Yes, but the Context for the ViewCell will be `MinRepresentation` which is what you are providing it. So your TapGestureRecognizer Command binding is expecting the Source Property (OrderDetailsCommand) to be in `MinRepresentation`.

Comment: Did this work for you yet?

Comment: @Cheesebaron That means, i have to set a Bindpath, like that ?

`Command="{Binding Path=BindingContext.TapCommand, Source={x:Reference HomeViewModel}}" CommandParameter="{Binding OrderDetailsCommand}"`

Comment: @Erstingo It depends on where did you place your `OrderDetailsCommand`.

Comment: `public IMvxAsyncCommand OrderDetailsCommand` is declared in the ViewModel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the easy solution...

XAML:

```xml
<ListView HasUnevenRows="True" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding VisibleOrders}" ItemSelected="OnListViewItemSelected" ItemTapped="OnListViewItemTapped"/>
```

ViewModel:

```cs
    public IList<MinRepresentation> VisibleOrders { get; private set; }

    void OnListViewItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
            {
                MinRepresentation selectedItem = e.SelectedItem as MinRepresentation;
            }

            void OnListViewItemTapped(object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
            {
                MinRepresentation tappedItem = e.Item as MinRepresentation;

            }
```